# Meteor.isClient vs isServer when calling a method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am implementing an offline mode for my iOS and web app that I am building with `Meteor`.
So far the online mode works with an API, where I save and get all of my data using the `HTTP` package.
Now I have started setting up a local db to save data when the app is offline using this solution: [Link](http://rafaelquintanilha.com/offline-app-with-meteor-and-cordova/)

So now, I can get my web app to use the API, and my mobile app to save data locally, but I can't find a nice way to have one piece of code that would work with both of them.

So here is my code:

1 - Where I call my method

```
Meteor.call('createDocument', myDataToSave, function( error, result)
{
   console.log(error, result);
});
```

2 - My methods:

```
// First option
if( Meteor.isServer){
   Meteor.methods({
     createDocument: function( myDataToSave){
        console.log('is server2');
        return HTTP.post( API_URL, {
            data: myDataToSave
        });
     }
   });
}


// Second option
Meteor.methods({
   createDocument: function(myDataToSave {
     if (Meteor.isCordova) {
        alert('is cordova');
        return Documents.insert(myDataToSave);
     } else if( Meteor.isServer){
        console.log('is server');
        return HTTP.post( API_URL, {
            data: myDataToSave
        });
    } else {
        console.log(Meteor);
    }
  }
});
```

So now what I don't understand is that when I am on my web browser testing the app locally, if I use the second option (comment out the first one), I have in my logs that `Meteor.isClient` is `true`, as the last `else` is used.

If I use first option and comment out the second one, everything works fine, `Meteor.isServer` is `true`, so I can save my data to the `API`

So I guess my question is, how come in the same file, same way of calling it, `Meteor` returns a different environment ? Does it come from declaring `Metor.methods` inside or outside the `Meteor.isServer` ?

---

PS: I have found a solution to use both at the same time, which is to have two different methods, one for the `server` and one for `client`:

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
   var method = 'createDocumentClient';
} else {
   var method = 'createDocument';
}
Meteor.call(method, myDataToSave, function( error, result)
{
   console.log(error, result);
});
```

But even though this solution seems to work, I still don't have a clue why this works and the first option doesn't, and would really appreciate if someone could help me understanding what is going on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is at root or in `/lib`, the method will run first on the client, then on the server. This is done for *latency compensation* and on the client is referred to as *simulation*. The `.isServer` and `.isClient` give you control over what environment you want your code to run in.

If you put methods in `/client` then they will only run on the client and vice versa if you put them in `/server`.

With the new ES6 imports you have specific control over what gets imported into each environment.

Comment: That makes sense :) Thank you for your answer Michel !